# Display emoji panel with genymotion - keyboard/touch input?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, genymotion, emoji

I try with no luck to open the panel with `emoji icons` but cannot find if it is even possible on genymotion (?) Normally the input is from keyboard.

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 1):

press alt in your real keyboard, you can see the option in Language and Input.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings->Language and Input->Current Keyboard

Turn on the "Show Input Method" switch.

This will cause a keyboard to appear on the screen when you input text, just like the way android works on a device that doesn't have a hardware keyboard. You can use it to input emoji.

If there's a better way, or another way, I don't know about it.